# jQuery shortening long numbers with commas

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could this be done with `javascript/jQuery`:

```
<div class="number">99,123,123</div>
<div class="number">123,123,123</div>
<div class="number">1,123,123,123</div>
<div class="number">1,123,123,123,123</div>
```

To display as

```
99,123,123 // (only start converting after > 8 total digits)
123M // M stands of million
1B
1T
```

But I also need to keep the actual number, and only display the converted number.
I still need to have access to the un-converted number.

Comment: Yep, it's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: @Blender I made in php, but realized later I have to have access to the actual value. I suck at js.

Comment: _"Could this be done with javascript/query:"_  === _"Can you do it for me"_ Yes, it can be done, What have you tried?

Comment: @gdoron thanks for the down vote and useless reply.

Comment: Who said it was me(But I do think it should be downvoted for the lack of self research)... And actually I'm the middle of the jsFiddle for your question... Think twice please.

Comment: You don't show any effort (or at least, code) in trying to solve your problem. This way, you'll most likely not get a satisfactory answer. Do you have multiple fields to display? If so how do you want to store the values? In the element's `data`? In an array? How do you want to access it later? Your question has a thousand of possible answers.

Comment: @gdoron My research was done. I would have done the following: remove the commas, count the digits, create a new span display none for reference, replace the current div's content somehow (this would have taken me days to figure out). Instead of posting 5 different questions  and making several pathetic attempts at accomplishing this, I thought I'd ask this straight.

Comment: If you'd have put ^ that paragraph in the question itself from the beginning you wouldn't have downvotes imo.

Comment: Well people usually avoid walls of text. I try to keep my questions as clean as possible.

Comment: @domino. It's up to you, but you take a risk, and many times it ends with several downvotes... :( Anyway I finished writing my answer. Hope it will help you. Good luck,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('div.number').each(function(){
    var num = this.innerHTML.replace(/\D/g, "");
    var result;

    if (num.length < 9)
        return true;
    else if (num.length == 9)
        result = num.substr(0, 3) + 'M';
    else if (num.length > 9 && num.length < 12)   
        result = num.substr(0, num.length - 9) + 'B';
    else if (num.length > 12 && num.length < 15)   
        result = num.substr(0, num.length - 12) + 'T';

    this.innerHTML = '<span class="hidden">' + this.innerHTML + '</span>' + result;
});​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xtk7k/1)

You can also save the initial value with jQuery `data` function:

```
    ...
    else if (num.length > 12 && num.length < 15)   
        result = num.substr(0, num.length - 12) + 'T';

    $(this).data('previous-value', this.innerHTML);
    this.innerHTML = result;
});
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xtk7k/2)

Comment: So much for the DIY approach ;)

Comment: Seems like you forgot to store the original values somewhere.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté. Added that bit now.

Comment: I was hoping for the `.data()`, but as it works (and fits the vague OP's question), +1

Comment: @FabrícioMatté. the `data-*` attributes seem to be a good option, but he did mention a `<span>` in the comment to his question.

Comment: Oh yup, I see. And it's pretty easy to get a `span` inside of the element as well, nice answer. :P

Comment: That's not too far from what I imagined the/a solution would be like. I wasn't sure if there's a point in creating a new span. Maybe it could have just displayed differently to the user than the actual code? No idea. Anyway, thanks for the code.

Comment: @Christoph. I did it because I love the challenge. Helping him was the second motivation...

Answer (score 3):

If you suck at Javascript and are good at PHP just do it serverside and either:

a) store the original values in a javascript var
b) store the values in a hidden html-element OR: (imo best solution)
c) store the original values as `data`-attribute of the according element. You then could retrieve it like that: `$("your-element").data("original-value")`

Just show your php-code and we find a solution to make it work.

Comment: I probably would have gone with solution b). But since the page contains A LOT of these numbers, I'm looking for something more dynamic. Php was not my first choice because of that too.

Comment: @domino Especially if your page contains a lot of numbers, it is very inefficient to do this clientside and stall the client with the computation and a lot of repaints triggered by altering the html.

Comment: @domino Well i guess you are touching those values anyway, since this seems to be a dynamic page (and you already formatted them by inserting the separators?), so it should be near to none overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
var numbers = $('.number').map(function() {
  return $(this).text().replace(',', '');
});

for (i in numbers) {
  var number = parseInt(numbers[i], 10);
  var number_of_digits = numbers[i].length;

  // ...
}
```

Comment: How does this answer anything?

Comment: It iterates over the numbers in the elements and for each one gives you the number's length and the number itself. I'm not going to code everything.

Comment: So... You just ignored the DRY problem and complained about the DRY in my answer... :(